# SFML display window behind all others

Tags: java, windows, desktop, sfml

I am using the Java binding for SFML. I want to display a `RenderWindow` behind all others - so that its straight above my desktop wallpaper but behind all the other windows that are open. It doesn't need to be platform independent - a solution for Windows would suffice.
I searched for something like a `.toBack()` method in the RenderWindow class but unfortunately there is none.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with SFML because SFML don't provide such facilities.

Comment: then - is there a windows-function that can be used to order the windows?

Comment: I don't know Windows API, but with a simple search I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx